# How can I get the name of the user that has logged into Oracle/Set up ssh to not need a username?

Tags: bash, oracle

I'm writing a script that will scp some files without requiring a password from my local database to a remote database. Currently, I've set up ssh (following these directions: http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html) and I'm able to use

```
scp /home/oracle/sendfiles/* myUsername@remoteServer:/home/oracle/receivefiles/
```

To send files over. However, this requires my script to have `myUsername` hard-coded for it to work. I'd like to be able to run

```
scp /home/oracle/sendfiles/* remoteServer:/home/oracle/receivefiles/
```

So that other users can use my script without having to specify their username. Is there a different way to set up ssh so I don't need to specify a username? Right now when I run my script without specifying my username it prompts me for `oracle@remoteServer`'s password.

Comment: If your username is the same on both servers then your second command will do what you want,for you and other users? And if not, you (and everyone else who uses the script) could specify their own name in their `~.ssh/config` file for that target, but that may be overkill here... But what does this have to do with Oracle, and where does `myUsername:oracle;default$` come from - is that just your shell prompt?

Comment: @AlexPoole When I run the scp command without specifying a username, I get a prompt for oracle@remoteServer's password, so I'm wondering if maybe I set up ssh incorrectly. Thinking on it more, using $currentUser@remoteServer won't work for my purposes so if I can get it to work without specifying a user that would be perfect

Comment: OK, so you're running the script from the `oracle` account on your local server. Should the files be created under the `oracle` account on the remote server too, or as under your own user ID there? I suspect, not least from the location, that they should stay owned by Oracle - so all the key stuff on both boxes should have been done as `oracle` too? (As an aside, you might want `scp -p` to preserve timestamps and permissions on the files as well.)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes, they would be under the `oracle` account on the remote server as well. I followed all the steps for setting up my ssh key as Oracle, not as myself. Additionally, my id_rsa.pub file ends in `oracle@localServer` as opposed to `myUsername@localServer`. Thanks, I appreciate the tip for `scp -p`! Didn't think of that.

Comment: You generated the key as `oracle`; but whose `authorized_keys` file did you add it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you seem to have run `ssh-keygen` as `oracle` on your local server, but added the contents of the locally-generated `/home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file to your *own* `authorized_keys` file - i.e. `/home/myUsername/.ssh/authorized_keys` - on the remote server.

From context I suspect you, and other users, log in to your local and remote boxes under your own accounts and then `su` to the `oracle` account. With the way you've set up the keys, any local user who can get to the `oracle` account on the local server now has access to your personal account on the remote server - which is not what you intended.

And although your first command specifying the remote user name works, the files on the remote end will be owned by you rather than `oracle`; which means the target directory `/home/oracle/receivefiles/` must be at least group- and possibly world-writable. That may not be necessary, and generally isn't a good idea - opinions vary but home directories tend to be locked down as tightly as possible, particularly for sensitive accounts like that one. (You don't want someone who gains access to the server with low privs to be able to do something nasty by, say, editing Oracle's `.profile` or creating some new dot file which, for instance, deletes all the DB data files next time someone logs into that account...)

The contents of `id_rsa.pub` need to be added to `/home/oracle/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote server (and should be removed from `/home/myUsername/.ssh/authorized_keys`!). Once you've done that, you and anyone else that has `su`'d to `oracle` on the local server will be able to do:

```
scp -p /home/oracle/sendfiles/* remoteServer:/home/oracle/receivefiles/
```

without being prompted for a password, and the files at the remote end will be owned by `oracle` instead of you. (The `-p` flag means permissions and timestamps will be preserved too.)

Comment: Ah, you were right. I set this up in a hurry yesterday and added `id_rsa.pub`'s contents to my user's home directory on the remote server... I've fixed it and it's working now. Thank you!